# Time calculation for NLTK tagging

Tags: python, machine-learning, natural-language-processing, benchmarking

I am trying to calculate the time required to tag one sentence/file by one trained NLTK HMM Tagger.
To do this I am writing the following code, please suggest if I need to revise anything here.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus.reader import TaggedCorpusReader
import time
#HMM 
reader = TaggedCorpusReader('/python27/', r'.*\.pos')
f1=reader.fileids()
print f1
sents=reader.tagged_sents()
ls=len(sents)
print "Total No of Sentences:",ls
train_sents=sents[0:40]
test_sents=sents[41:46]
#TRAINING & TESTING
hmm_tagger=nltk.HiddenMarkovModelTagger.train(train_sents)
test=hmm_tagger.test(test_sents)
appli_sent1=reader.sents(fileids='minicv.pos')[0]
print "SAMPLE INPUT:",appli_sent1
start_time = time.clock()
application=hmm_tagger.tag(appli_sent1) #I MAY REPLACE WITH ONE DOCUMENT 
print "ENTITY RECOGNIZED",application 
print "Time Taken Is:",time.clock() - start_time, "seconds"
```

*NB: This is a toy kind example and I did not follow much of training/testing size parameters.*